# transform crushed the container above flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a code that contains a column, and in the column there are 3 widgets, a widget container that has a height of 200 and a width of 200 in red, and the second widget contains a container with a child a transform scale that contains an image that I want to scale, and widget 3 contains the same as the first widget, every time I scale the image, what happens to the second container is always past the first container but does not occur with continaer to 3, if in css I will definitely use zindex, is there some kind of flutter zindex

this is the code

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 300,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      Container(
        // height: 397,
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: 2.0,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Image(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com//kriyapeople/8fa208d6-1486-4028-bd23-243581b4d3a7"),
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        height: 300,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ],
  )));
```

and the result of that code 
[image]

Comment: Do you want to achieve something like in that image?

Comment: the image is the broken one

Answer (score 0):

Use `Stack` widget,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildHeader(),
          for (final i in List.generate(20, (i) => i))
            ListTile(title: Text("Tile $i")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildHeader() {
    double height = 250;
    return SizedBox(
      height: height,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: height * 2 / 3,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                height: height / 3,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Image(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com//kriyapeople/8fa208d6-1486-4028-bd23-243581b4d3a7"),
              height: height * 2/3,
              width: height * 2/3,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```